# K,V pair with the first element from array string in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a RDD of `Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(12345, 1232A, 66QQ2, ASC42, 0003A, 2294AA, AGDT33, 23881), Array(536366, 22633, 22632)....)`

i want the output to be

```
Array[(String, String)] = Array((12345,1232A), (12345,66QQ2)....
```

Comment: Please add more details about what have you tried so far to solve this problem?

Comment: i was trying `rdd.flatMap{case Array(s1, s2) => s2.split(",").map(part => (s1, part))}` it didnt worked

Comment: xlr, check my answer. I think it should give you the output you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an rdd Map and  [Stream](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html) to zip the head of each interior array with every element of its tail.

```
val test: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array("12345", "1232A", "66QQ2", "ASC42", "0003A", "2294AA", "AGDT33", "23881"), Array("536366", "22633", "22632"))
val TestRdd = sc.parallelize(test)
val finalOutput: Array[(String,String)] = (TestRdd map(xs => (Stream.continually(xs.head) zip xs.tail).toList)).flatten

// finalOutput is 
// res8: Array[(String, String)] = Array((12345,1232A), (12345,66QQ2), (12345,ASC42), (12345,0003A), (12345,2294AA), (12345,AGDT33), (12345,23881), (536366,22633), (536366,22632))
```

Comment: If my solution meets your needs, please mark it as the correct answer so anyone else who views this question can find it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try `flatmap` transformation and emit first element of array with rest of the elements:

```
rdd.flatMap(s => {
      var output = new ListBuffer[Tuple2[String,String]]()
      for (i <- 1 to (s.length - 1)) {
        output+=((s(0), s(i)) )
      }
      output
    }).foreach(println);
```

Comment: thanks it worked too, but took a while to give the output